# Performance of PG_DUMP vs Replication with master/slave?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, pg-dump

I need to backup my database and the 2 options I'm considering are:

1. Use `pg_dump` to do daily dumps.
2. Set up a slave database that will be a replication of the master.

I'm not asking which one is the best option, but rather:

- How does the performance of these 2 compare?

  Intuitively, both are doing similar things, which is streaming all the data in 1 single process from 1 server to another.
- Which one of the 2 has less of an impact CPU/load-wise on the master database server?
- Which one will have less of an impact on the current queries being processed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an apples to oranges type of question. pg_dump gives you a logical backup of your database, which you can manipulate or move to other systems to reload as an internally-consistent database. The replicated slave is an exact copy of the live master, which changes as the master changes. Now, if you wanted to go for a hybrid approach, you could set up replication between master and slave, and configure the hot standby so that you could take a pg_dump *from* the slave. That's the method I usually employ in production environments because of the flexibility and reduced impact on the master.

Comment: So my question is: What's the impact of having a slave database? I mean, what's the equivalency? Is it just one extra process that's doing a very large streaming select query? Can I think of the impact that way?

Comment: There is certainly a one-off hit you will take when you clone the master for a base backup (eg. using `pg_basebackup`). After that though, the replication -- whether Streaming Replication or WAL segment shipping -- is pretty low impact. Nothing that does something is ever free, but unless you are very resource constrained you probably won't even notice the slave. Of course, vagaries of your hardware and topology can colour my simplified explanation, but in the general case replication's impact is pretty low.